# How to use a value from text file to do a calculation

Tags: vb.net, file, io, streamreader

I am trying to do a calculation using a value stored in my text file to reset my PLC counter. Below is what I have done so far.

```
 Dim PileValue_txt As String = "C:\test.txt"
 Dim Value As New System.IO.StreamReader(PileValue_txt)
 ValueTextbox1.Text =  Value.ReadToEnd
 Value.Close()

Convert.ToIntCInt32(Value)
LastValue = Value

  If 9999 < LastValue Then 
  CounterValue = 32000 * 1000 'Counter will reset

End if
```

But It threw an exception on `(If 9999 < LastValue)`

> Error Message: Operator is not defined for type ‘integer’ and ‘system.io.streamreader’

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(Value)` returns a value which you need to assign to a variable. It does not magically change a stream to an integer from the stream. If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it will allow Visual Studio to point out problems like that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `Value` as a `StreamReader` And the content are assigned to `ValueTextBox1` using `ReadLine()` method.

You have to use

```
LastValue = CInt(ValueTextbox1.Text)
```

Instead of

```
Convert.ToIntCInt32(Value)
LastValue = Value
```

And you can read more about reading text content at this [Stackoverflow documentation](http://www.riptutorial.com/dot-net/example/29/reading-a-text-file-using-streamreader) part

Comment: Thanks @ H.Fadlallah, it threw another error message: "value of type integer cannot be converted to 'system.io.streamreader

Comment: `LastValue` is declared as `integer`?

Comment: If not. you have to store this value `CInt(ValueTextbox1.Text)` in an integer variable

Comment: Thanks @ H.Fadlallah that fix it